# array.protorype.map / array.prototype.reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
   return arr.map(function(group){
    return group.reduce(function(prev, current) {
      return (current > prev) ? current : prev;
    });
  });
}
```

Folks, just saw this kind of use array.map and array.reduce in one function. The truth, I am new w/ map and reduce functions. But think fits well for cracking head on this function, for getting deep in map/reduce functions? What do you think, any other resources for this issue?

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://medium.com/javascript-scene/composing-software-an-introduction-27b72500d6ea to help you get a better understanding of map and reduce.

Comment: This maps an array with the reduction of its inner array. So [[1,2,3],[4,5,6] will be mapped to [3,6]

Comment: You could start with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) their documentation is second to none, with good examples. Also if you are interested in functional side of JS I highly recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0zVEGEvSaeEd9hlmCXrk5yUyqUag-n84) playlist from MPJ.